# Function inside function in C

Tags: c, gcc, nested-function

Anybody please elaborate these error:-

```
void main()
{
    int a=5, b=60, func();

    printf("\nI am in main-1");

    int func(){
        printf("\nI am in funct");
        return 1;
    }
    func();
    printf("\nI am in main-2");
}
```

The errors I get are:

- In function 'main':
- Line 8: error: static declaration of 'func' follows non-static
  declaration
- Line 4: error: previous declaration of 'func' was here
- Line 3: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'

I think C allows nested class because the following code is working fine:

```
void outerfunc()
{
    int func()
    {
        printf("\nI am in funct");
        return 1;
    }

    func();
}

void main()
{
    printf("\nI am in main-1");

    outerfunc();
    printf("\nI am in main-2");
}
```

Comment: `void main` **ARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHH!**

Comment: Also, `main()` returns `int` in C.

Comment: That shows you are not reading a book, a Good Book that is.
`The Definitive C Book Guide and List`  -  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @pmg: I always wonder why people get so bothered about `void main()`.  The C standard doesn't prohibit it.

Comment: @Oli, it is allowed *as an extension* for hosted implementations. Using it, makes your program not portable **and there's no gain whatsoever in reducing portability in this case**. It is allowed for free-standing implementations that document it as such.

Comment: @OP - `I think C allows nested class because the following code is working fine` - Don't think, start reading buddy :-) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c

Comment: @pmg: 5.1.2.2.3 says "**If** the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int...", in the context of hosted environments. That sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @Oli, a little further up, in 5.1.2.2.1, the Standard says (re-phrased): "main shall be defined as int main(void) or some other implementation-defined manner". Note the **shall** :-)

Comment: @pmg @Oli The return type of main is inconsequential to the question itself. `void myOtherFunc()` would work just as well here, as it would in most other quesitons where people complain `void main()`.

Comment: @Iron: "How many gallons of petrol does your car take?" / "My car takes runs on diesel" / "The type of fuel is inconsequential to the question" / "the tank has a capacity of 50 liters" / ... next thing you know the car explodes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using an extension of the GNU C Compiler which allows the declarations of nested functions. The error comes from the fact, that forward declarations of nested functions under GCC's extension need to be prepended with the `auto` keyword.

```
int a=20,b=11;
int main()
{
  int a=5, b=60; 
  auto int func(); // <--------- here
  func(); // <- call it
  printf("\nI am in main-1");

  int func(){
  printf("\nI am in funct");
  return 1;
  }

printf("\nI am in main-2");
 return 0;
}
```

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html for more details.

Answer (score 9):

ANSI C doesn't allow nested function definition. And your main function should return **int**.

Comment: [Yes it does](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) (at least as a GCC "extension" of C)

Comment: Apparently (from the error messages one can tell), he is using gcc which in fact has nested functions!

Comment: @Justin ok, to be more accurate, ANSI C

Comment: @Oli Fair enough, but the poster said "C", not "ANSI C".

Comment: @Oli: OP didn't say that he uses ANSI-C

Answer (score 1):

**Nested functions are not allowed** in standard C/C++. Simply (forward) declare the `func()` inside `main()` if you want to define it later on.

```
int main()
{
  int a=5, b=60, func();

printf("\nI am in main-1");

  int func();  // <---- declare inside main()

printf("\nI am in main-2");
}


int func(){    // <---- define later
  printf("\nI am in funct");
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are taking about is a [GCC specific feature](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html), its never been a "proper" C feature (i.e. part of the ANSI C specification).

If you want to use this feature then I believe what you are after is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 20, b = 11;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int a = 5, b = 60;
    auto int func( void );

    printf("\nI am in main-1");

    int func( void )
    {
        printf("\nI am in funct");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nI am in main-2");
    return func();
}
```

The reason why your previous code didn't work is because nested functions have no linkage:

> A nested function always has no linkage. Declaring one with extern or static is erroneous. If you need to declare the nested function before its definition, use auto (which is otherwise meaningless for function declarations).

The above sample uses the `auto` keyword thusly.  I've also taken the liberty of fixing your `main` declaration :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions are a gcc-specific [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html); they are not universally supported.

As far as the warning about `main`, the standard signatures for main are

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char **argv) // or equivalent
```

An implementation *may* provide additional signatures (some compilers allow a third parameter for environment variables), but those additional signatures **must be documented** by the implementation; IOW, `void main()` is only a valid signature for `main` if your compiler documentation explicitly lists it as such.

When in doubt, use one of the standard signatures above.

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't defined `func` before calling it.
2. Relates back to the original line.
3. You aren't returning int.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the declaration of `func()` in the `int` variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow functions to be included inside other functions.

Attempting to do so in VS 2010 gives:

**'funct' : local function definitions are illegal**

You need to move that function and it's declaration outside of main.