# can I call a function that was written in another function?

Tags: c, function, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c)

In C, if i wrote a program in this structure:

```
main ()
{
  int function1(...)
  {
    ....
  }
}

function 2()
{
   function1(...)
}
```

It is possible to call function1 from function2 that was written inside the main function?
and also:
In C all the functions are global? or there is some restriction in some situation that from one function you cant call another one?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c

Comment: You can't nest functions in _C_, and you can't call them `2` either

Comment: Also, you can't write functions in C without a return type, that is an obsolete style no longer valid in the current standard.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. This question applies to scope, not if it is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest function definitions in C.

```
int main(void)
{
  int function1(void)
  {
      /* ... */
  }
}
```

The definition of `function1` above is not valid.

Comment: Euhm. When I try, I can. gcc 4.6.3

Comment: @BartFriederichs this is valid in GNU C, see  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html but not in C.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Who cares about the non-standard GNU-goo language? Compile with a C compiler. Conveniently, GCC also supports the C language: `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

In GNU C is possible to nest functions. I tried this little snippet and it worked

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void printy() { printf("hallo\n"); }

    printy();
}
```

like GNU C page claims http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

**The nested function's name is local to the block where it is defined**

Infact, if i change my code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func2();

int main()
{
    void printy() { printf("hallo\n"); }

    printy();

    func2();
}

void func2()
{
    printy();
}
```

i get

```
gcc test.c
/tmp/ccGhju4n.o: In function `func2':
test.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `printy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is too vague, you can declare a function inside another function but you can't define it. However, the downvote isn't mine.

Comment: you're right and i was wrong... i edited my post... it's incredible how many thing i don't know but i was sure i knew them

Comment: @DavideBerra That's because you're calling `printy` outside the scope in which it was defined (which is `main`). The answers that say you can't do this in C are correct, but if gcc allows it as an extension you still have to expect normal rules of scope to apply.