# Syntax Error: expected declaration at end of input

Tags: c, syntax

I keep getting a strange syntax error that i've never seen before, and I'm not sure what's the problem with it. Can I get some extra eyes to help me figure out what the problem is?

the error reads: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input the bold line is what it highlights as the error.

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
     int i; 

     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
           cards;
           putchar('\n');
           }

void cards()
{
         char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};

         for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {       
        if(i%13 == 0 || i%13 == 10 || i%13 == 11 || i%13 == 12)
            printf("%s ", facecheck(i%13) );
        else printf("%d ", i%13+1);
        printf("of %s \n", suits[i/13]);
    };

**}**
```

Comment: how have a semi column after } where it shouldn't be (the } related to the for)

Comment: Dude - match the curly braces :)

Comment: Perhaps proper indentation would help.

Comment: That, and terminating "draw()" with the closing brace :)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close `draw` function. You're missing a `}` at the end:

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
     int i; 
     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
           cards;
           putchar('\n');
     }
} //ADD ME PLEASE :(
```

As stated on the comments, a good IDE could have caught this before compiling.

I also recommend you to indent your code so you can better match opening/closing braces.

Your code suffers from additional errors, I highly recommend you to read a tutorial and to review your code.

Comment: Also worth noting, a good IDE (even Notepad++, to some extent) will catch this before you compile.

Answer (score 1):

'cards;' looks suspect as it's the name of a function

Comment: True, it's a logic error, but I don't think that's a compiler error. http://liveworkspace.org/code/2dp6eB%241

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @chris No, it's a syntax error, not a logic error ... C doesn't allow nested functions. Your snippet isn't relevant.

Comment: @eugen danf doesn't have enough rep to leave comments. It's one of those SO policies that makes little sense, because it just encourages beginners to post their comments as answers.

Comment: @JimBalter, The definition of `cards` would be, yes, but `cards;` itself, provided there's a forward declaration, should not. It just needlessly evaluates it.

Comment: @chris Sorry, I thought danf was referring to the major error (the definition of `cards` occurring within the scope of `draw`). I should have paid more attention. "It just needlessly evaluates it." -- well, it declares it; it doesn't evaluate anything -- but it presumably should. But then a declaration *is* needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {       
           if(i%13 == 0 || i%13 == 10 || i%13 == 11 || i%13 == 12)
           printf("%s ", facecheck(i%13) );
           else printf("%d ", i%13+1);
           printf("of %s \n", suits[i/13]);
        }; //no need of semi-colon after curly brace
    }
 } //missing curly brace
```

Comment: Whoever has given me -1 on this answer, please tell me where I'm wrong, so that I won't repeat it in future. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it completely misses the real problem ... that's the wrong place for the missing curly. Also, your edit of the OP's question makes it much worse.

Comment: I'm not saying that you downvoted me, I just asked about my mistake.Why it's the wrong place for missing curly brace?It could be possible that cards is defined inside draw, ain't it?

Comment: "I'm not saying that you downvoted me" -- And I didn't say you said that, I simply noted that I'm not that person. "I just asked about my mistake" -- you asked it of the person who downvoted you. If I hadn't said I did not, it would have been reasonable to assume that I did. "It could be possible" -- No, that's not legal C; did you try it?

Comment: "it works in gcc" -- if your flags allow extensions. However, this is not tagged [gcc]. "not sure" -- No, it definitely is not legal C. "Yep" -- If you're going to answer questions tagged [c] at SO, you need to become more familiar with the language so that your answers don't reflect gcc idiosyncrasies ... possibly with the help of flags like -ansi -pedantic

Comment: You're welcome. Here's more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c