# Regarding nested function in C

Tags: c, function, nested

The following link mentions that nested functions do not exist in C

> [Nested function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c)

In following file function mini_vsnprintf has nested functions

> https://github.com/mludvig/mini-printf/blob/master/mini-printf.c

Q: Do nested functions really exist in C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard C does not support nested functions.

GCC does support nested functions.

Generally, don't use nested functions if you want your code to be portable.

Comment: What is the use of using nested functions without implementing closure since the nested function can be invoked only in the lexical scope of the parent function?

Comment: I don't have a use for nested functions.  The GCC compiler writers obviously do, so you'd do best to ask them.