# Test Function Not Working C Programming

Tags: c

I am attempting to write code that checks the validity of a date [day and month only], inputs that date [day and month] into a "Date" structure, and then, finally, checks that the code in fact did what I expected it to do in a test function, by printing "SUCCESS" if successful, or "FAILURE" if not;

I have tried everything, and cannot think of what the problem might be; I am getting no warnings, so debugger didnt help. the code compiles and runs, however, there is nothing being printed on screen to let me know if it is actually working or not;

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "PatientData.h"
#define INVALID -100
#define SUCCESS 0

int main()

{

int datechecker(int month, int day) {
    int ret = SUCCESS;
    month = 2;
    day = 2;
    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8
            || month == 10 || month == 12)
    {
        if(!(day >= 1 && day <= 31))
          ret = INVALID;
    }
    else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
    {
        if(!(day >= 1 && day < 31 ))
            ret = INVALID;
    }

    else
    {
        ret = INVALID;
    }
return(ret);
}


Date CreateDate(int day, int month)
{

Date date;

int ret = datechecker(2,2);
if (ret == SUCCESS)
{
date.Day = day;
date.Month = month;
}
else
{
    date.Day = INVALID;
}

return date;

}


void CreateDateTest ()
{
Date date = CreateDate(2,2);
if (date.Day == 2)
{
    printf("PASSED");
}
else
{
    printf("FAILED");
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you can never have a date in February; it will always be invalid.  Pity that you're forcing the date to 2nd February.

Comment: Guess you are not a fan of leap years?!

Comment: lol, shoot, didn't even realize I used February and did not include it in the code; GD IT!!!!!! 

will report back

Comment: So I changed it to call a function with day and month variables that were actually defined in the date checker function, still didnt work :\

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have three functions defined inside `main`, called `CreateDate`, `CreateDateTest`, and `datechecker`. However, the lone executable statement inside `main` is `return 0`, which is what your program is faithfully doing.

Your code cannot be run as such since `PatientData.h` is not available, but I suspect it will work once you call `CreateDateTest` from `main`.

Comment: [Nested functions are not standard C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c).  GCC allows them as an extension, but it seems unlikely this is what the OP really wants, anyway.

Comment: I created a header file and included it in both the script where I define the functions [which is the same as the code in the question], and what they do, as well as the script that has my test function;

However, for the script that includes my test function [same test function as in the code above,

Comment: @Zeus: Even if you use (accidentally) non-standard features, you still have to call functions before they are executed.  Since you must be using GCC, it is worth adding warning options to your compilation.  You might consider the merits of `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror …`; they're demanding, but they prevent a lot of problems too.  Adding `-pedantic` and `-Wshadow` can also be helpful on occasion.

Comment: I'm using the eclipse IDE which comes loaded with warning option features;