# Why doesn't control enter the repeat() function?

Tags: c

"Rewrite numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at the input are integers of one or two digits."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num ;

    int repeat()
    {  
        scanf("%d",&num) ;
        if(num!=42)
        {
             printf("\n%d",num) ;
             repeat() ;
        }
        else
        {
            return num ;
        }
        getch() ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nested function definitions are not standard C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not really.

Comment: @melpomene You can declare a function inside of another function. You cannot *define* one though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @melpomene Then what "not really" is related to? *Update:* Oh, I see, that it is inside it's own definition. Missed this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187325/discussion-between-melpomene-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Thanks for the help

```
#include <stdio.h>
int repeat(int num) 
    {  
        scanf("%d",&num) ;
        if(num!=42)
        {
               printf("%d",num) ;
               repeat(num) ;
        }
    else
    {
        return num ;
    }
    getch() ;
    }

int main() {
       int num ;
       scanf("%d",&num) ;
       repeat(num) ;
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why do Control don't enter repeat() function?

Because `main()` does not call it.

The `repeat()` function is defined inside `main()`. Which is non standard. Moving it out makes things clearer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num ;

int repeat()
{  
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num != 42)
    {
        printf("\n%d", num);

        repeat();
    }
    else
    {
        return num ;
    }

    getch();
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

From the above it is obvious that `main()` in fact does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You created the function repeat() but you never call it Also you should pass num as an argument to repeat() and expect it to return.