# Unexpected return value of a function called by a function pointer

Tags: c

The return value of the function "fun" is unexpected

I'm learning C by writing a high order function "funfun" to return a function "fun"

```
#include<stdio.h>
void* funfun(const int k) {
    int fun(const int c) {
            //int sum = k + c;
            printf("k = %d, c = %d, sum = %d\n", k, c, k + c);
            return k + c;
    }
    return fun;
}

int main() {
    int (*ptr)(int) = funfun(3);
    printf("%d\n", ptr(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Commenting out "int sum = k + c;", the display is unexpected:

```
k = 3, c = 2, sum = 5
134513986
```

Keeping that line, the display is expected:

```
k = 3, c = 2, sum = 5
5
```

The code is compiled and executed with:

```
gcc a.c -o a && ./a
```

gcc -v shows:

```
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with C, but I imagine it's because `k` isn't "bound" like closures in other languages. Just a guess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You are using a GCC extension called [Nested Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

In that documentation, you can discover that what you are doing is not allowed:

> But this technique works only so long as the containing function (hack, in this example) does not exit.

The "containing function" is `funfun` in your case.

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, **all hell breaks loose**.

C does not really have higher-order functions (with closures etc.). This extension to C doesn't really provide those either.