# Nested Functions in C

Tags: c, function

I read that nested function don't exist in C.
I then successfully executed the following piece of code using the cc command on my linux machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    float dummy(){
        printf("hello\n");
    }
    dummy();
    return 0;
}
```

I got the the output `hello`.

How does that play out?
Does my compiler support nested functions?

Answer (score 1):

[GNU C supports nested functions as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).  Your `cc` binary on your Linux machine is almost certainly a symlink to `gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions don't exist in standard C. However, it might be supported as an extension in certain compilers like [GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

Comment: Dupe of [Nested function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c)