# C: Making a polynomial function via command line arguments

Tags: c, polynomials, calculus, ti-basic

For my Calculus class it has been asked frequently to find the average speed between two points to find the instantaneous speed, requiring me to do `f(b) - f(a) / b - a`. I want to do pass parameters to program (eventually loaded onto my Ti-84) to solve this for me quickly, ideally
working like this: `./a.out 2 4 -1 , 2.9 2.9999` resulting in the polynomial `2x^2 + 4x - 1`, which would be ran on both `2.9` and `2.9999`. So far I have written most of the logic in this code, however I am having difficulty putting it into proper C.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int comma; // Ex: ` ./a.out 1 2 3 , 4 5 ` comma is at index 3
        // Find out where comman is located
        for ( int i=1;i<argc; i++)
        {
                if (argv[i] == ','){
                        int comma = i;
                        break;
                }
        }

        printf("%d", comma);

        // PSUEDO-CODE START
        //
        // Problem: f(b) - f(a) / b - a
        //
        // Idea
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // ./a.out 7 2 3 , 2 5
        // // Right now argc is 6
        // // Right now comma is 4
        // polynomialOrder = argc - comma
        //
        // // Get bigger number for the / b - a part
        // firstNum  = argv[comma + 1]
        // secondNum = argv[comma + 2]
        // biggerNum = ( firstNum > secondNum ) ? firstNum : secondNum;
        // smallerNum = ( firstNum < secondNum ) ? firstNum : secondNum;
        //
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        // Psuedo-code:
        //
        // for  (int i=polynomialOrder; i >= 0; i--)
        // {
        //      if (i == 0){ function += argv[i]} // I don't want 3x^2 + 2x^1 + 4^0 , the
4^0 should be 4
        //      else{
        //              // Generate a function?
        //              polynomial += argv[i]^i;  // The += appends to the function
        //      }
        // }
        // // result is -7x^2 + 2x^1 + 1
        //
        // Function generated:
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // float polynomial(a, b) {
        //      float result;
        //      float a_result = (-7*(a**2)) + (2*(a**1)) + 1;
        //      float b_result = same as ^, substitute in b
        //      float result = (b_result - a_result) / ( b - a);
        //      return return;
        // }
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // }
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        // polynomial( smallerNum, biggerNum );

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am having difficulty putting it into proper C." What is the problem? What symptoms?

Comment: For `./a.out 7 2 3 , 2 5`, you should have `argc == 7` and you will see that `argv[0]` points to the string `./a.out`.

Comment: Although your compiler may allow it, you should not define `polynomial()` inside `main()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608158/nested-function-in-c

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Wrong compare**

`','` is not a string and is an invalid argument to `strcmp()`.  `strcmp()` returns 0 when strings are equal.

```
// if (strcmp(argv[i], ',')) // Check if arg is ','
if (strcmp(argv[i], ",") == 0) // Check if arg is ","
```

**Local object**

`comma` is only local to the block.  This `comma` cease to exist after the break.  Later `polynomialOrder = argc - comma;`  has no `comma` to access.

```
{
   printf("Parameters to function");
   int comma = i; // All before are parts of function, after params
   break;
}
```

**Invalid power code**

```
// (-7*(a**2)) + (2*(a**1)) + 1;
-7*pow(a,2) + 2*pow(a,1) + 1;
// or 
-7*a*a + 2*a + 1;
// or numerical best stability as 
(-7*a + 2)*a + 1;
```

**`float` vs. `double`**

Use `float` when space is critical or speed is critical over precision/range.  In C, best to use `double` as the default *floating point* type.

**Post compiler warnings/errors**

OP's code fails to compile.  Post your errors, warnings, and detailed questions about remaining issues.

If all the code was meant to be *pseudo-code*, post that at the beginning of code.