# Can we declare and define a function inside an existing function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
void function(int entry, int x1, int x2)
{
    void (*new_func)(int n1, int n2);
    new_func = (void (*)(int, int)) entry;
    
    new_func(x1,x2);
    
}
```

Lets say we have this function, there is a function new_func which is declared and defined and called from within the function.
Is this allowed ? Is this possible ?

This code is compiling but while debugging it seems to be exiting.

Comment: `new_func` is not function, it's a function pointer.

Comment: You are casting an `int` value to a function pointer. This is rather dubious.

Comment: Can you show how you call this function? And also explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: does `void function(void entry(int,int), int x1, int x2) { new_function(x1, x2); }` work for you?

Comment: Among other things, this assumes that an `int` is large enough to hold a function pointer. On many systems that is not true.

Comment: What does `entry` point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `new_func` is not a function, it's a function pointer.

The code snippet that you have shown in your question is casting an `int` value to a function pointer of type `void (*)(int, int)` and assigning it to `new_func`:

```
new_func = (void (*)(int, int)) entry;
```

but you haven't mentioned what argument is passed to `entry` parameter of `function()` function.
Are you type casting a function pointer to `int` and passing it as first argument to function `function()`?

Your program can either have implementation defined behaviour or undefined behaviour depending on value of first argument passed `function()` function.

From *C11#6.3.2.3p5*

> 5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.67)

From *C11#6.3.2.3p6*

> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions are not a part of the standard. However, some compilers support this as extensions. Like `gcc`. Read more about nested functions in C here [Nested function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2608158/6699433)

However, that's not what's going on here. In your code it's a function pointer. Read more about that here: [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/6699433)

And without seeing the whole code, I'd say that `entry` probably has wrong type. It should probably be `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`. [What is the uintptr_t data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/6699433)