# static declaration follows non-static declaration error message

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The compiler is giving me an error message on

```
line 20: "static declaration of ‘timeDifference’ follows non-static declaration"
```

and then another one on

```
line 12: "previous declaration of ‘timeDifference’ was here"
```

I know it has something to do with my function 'timeDifference'. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

main ()
{
    int timeDifference (struct time  diff);

    struct time  early, late, difference;

    printf ("Enter Start Time hh:mm:ss ");

    scanf  ("%d:%d:%d", &early.hours, &early.minutes, &early.seconds);

    printf ("Enter End Time hh:mm:ss ");

    scanf  ("%d:%d:%d", &late.hours, &late.minutes, &late.seconds);

    int timeDifference (struct time  diff)
    {
            if (late.seconds < early.seconds)
            late.seconds += 60;
            late.minutes -= 1;
            if (late.minutes < early.minutes)
            late.minutes += 60;
            late.hours -= 1;
            if (late.hours < early.hours)
            late.hours += 24;

            diff.seconds = late.seconds - early.seconds;
            diff.minutes = late.minutes - early.minutes;
            diff.hours   = late.hours   - early.hours;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have prototype of function and the definition in the body of your `main`. Move the prototype to before the `main`, and the function after the `main`.

Comment: @AntonH the prototype can well remain inside main.

Comment: Read the basics first before trying. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

Comment: Related Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090975/function-definition-inside-another-function-definition-is-it-valid

Answer (score 1):

You can't have one function inside another in C. The declaration of `timeDifference` on line 12, and the function itself (the definition) starting at line 20, need to be moved outside your `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition of `timeDifference` outside `main()` function. According to C standard such construct is not defined. Some compilers do take it but in your case the compiler seems to have given up.

Answer (score 0):

you can't declare a function inside another function, Move timeDifference outside the `main`
 beside you didn't give `main` a return-type, make it `int main()`

Answer (score 0):

Although the following code is not complete, perhaps it will help you along your way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time
   {
   int hours;
   int minutes;
   int seconds;
   };

int timeDifference(
      struct time *I__early,
      struct time *I__late,
      struct time *_O_diff
      )
   {
   if(I__late->seconds < I__early->seconds)
      I__late->seconds += 60;

   I__late->minutes -= 1;
   if(I__late->minutes < I__early->minutes)
      I__late->minutes += 60;

   I__late->hours -= 1;
   if (I__late->hours < I__early->hours)
      I__late->hours += 24;

   _O_diff->seconds = I__late->seconds - I__early->seconds;
   _O_diff->minutes = I__late->minutes - I__early->minutes;
   _O_diff->hours   = I__late->hours   - I__early->hours;

   return(0);
   }

int main()
   {
   struct time  early, late, difference;

   printf ("Enter Start Time hh:mm:ss ");
   scanf  ("%d:%d:%d", &early.hours, &early.minutes, &early.seconds);
   printf ("Enter End Time hh:mm:ss ");
   scanf  ("%d:%d:%d", &late.hours, &late.minutes, &late.seconds);

   timeDifference(&early, &late, &difference);
   ... 

   return(0);
   }
```