# Program not asking for new entry if you enter invalid choice in String format

Tags: c

I'm having a problem understanding how to get my `while` loop to simply output a message saying "Invalid Input" and asking for a new question from the user unless he chooses number `1` or `2` in the list. What happens if you for example input : `asdas` instead of a integer the program never stops looping.

What I would like to happen is for the program to tell the user to enter a new number from `1-2` instead of simply stopping running which i can achieve by setting the default in the switch to `exit(0);` or `runSystem = false;`

For example:

CMD Says enter `1-2` the user enters : `asdaf` (never stops looping) as in current situation.

What I want is: `asdf` and then it says "enter a new choice" and waits for a correct answer.

What bothers me is the fact that the program will do as i want it to if you enter an invalid number for example: `12312312` and ask for a new entry but it doesn't work with string input.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int userinput;
    int runSystem = true;

    void options() {
        printf("<========Welcome to the program, please make a choice========> \n\n");

        printf("1: Say Hello\n");
        printf("2: Say GoodBye\n");
        printf("Please enter a choice:");
        scanf("%d", &userinput);
    }

    while (runSystem) { 
        options();  
        switch(userinput) {         
           case 1: printf("Hello!\n");
           break;           
           case 2: printf("GoodBye!\n");
           break;       
           case 3: printf("Invalid, try again\n");
           break;       
           default: 
           break;       
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've defined `options` as a nested function inside of `main`. This is not valid C, and is onot supported as a GCC extension.

Comment: @jonathon-reinhart The question is not an exact duplicate of question 3744776: That question is about consuming whitespace in input. Here the OP inputs what he calls a String (he means a non-numerical string), and that is not consumed either by %d. So the solution could be to read a line of text with `fgets(…)` and then try parsing the line for an integer.

Comment: Good catch Renardo.

Comment: Step 1: Check the return value of `scanf("%d", &userinput);`

Answer (score 1):

Valid `C` compiler does not allow declaration of the function `options` inside the `main`.

Make that function returning your input and pass the returning value to the `switch`. Also in order to stop the `while` loop `case 2:` should change the `runSystem` to `false;`

> input : `asdas` instead of a integer the program never stops looping.

This is because when `scanf("%d", &userinput);` failed it did not updated the variable `userinput`.

Check the standard [7.21.6.4 The scanf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4).

You can read about behaviour of `scanf`
 [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

On success, the `scanf` returns the number of items successfully read. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens. In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, `EOF` is returned.

Knowing that you can check the return value of `scanf` and make appropriate decision. Presented solution eats the bad characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int options(void) {

    int c;   
    int ret;
    int x = 0;
    int error = 0;
    printf("<========Welcome to the program, please make a choice========> \n\n");

    printf("1: Say Hello\n");
    printf("2: Say GoodBye\n");

    printf("Please enter a choice:");

    while(1)
    {
        c = '0';

        if(!error)
            printf("Input a number:\n");
        else
           error = 0;

        ret = scanf("%d", &x);

        if(ret == EOF) {
            return 2; // END OF PROGRAM
        }
        else
        {
            if (ret == 1){
                return x;
            }
            else  // NOT a number
            {
                printf("No letters! Input a number:\n");
                do
                {
                    c = getchar();
                    if(c == EOF)
                       return 2; // END OF PROGRAM
                }
                while (!isdigit(c) && c!='\n');

                ungetc(c, stdin);
                error = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {

   int userinput;
   int runSystem = true;

   while (runSystem) {

        userinput = options();
        switch(userinput) {

            case 1: printf("Hello!\n");
            break;

            case 2: printf("GoodBye!\n");
                runSystem = false;
            break;

            default: 
            case 3: printf("Invalid, try again\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<========Welcome to the program, please make a choice========>                                                                                

1: Say Hello                                                                                                                                  
2: Say GoodBye                                                                                                                                
Please enter a choice:Input a number:                                                                                                         
X                                                                                                                                             
No letters! Input a number:                                                                                                                   
a                                                                                                                                             
No letters! Input a number:                                                                                                                   
1                                                                                                                                             
Hello!                                                                                                                                        
<========Welcome to the program, please make a choice========>                                                                                

1: Say Hello                                                                                                                                  
2: Say GoodBye                                                                                                                                
Please enter a choice:Input a number:                                                                                                         
7                                                                                                                                             
Invalid, try again                                                                                                                            
<========Welcome to the program, please make a choice========>                                                                                

1: Say Hello                                                                                                                                  
2: Say GoodBye                                                                                                                                
Please enter a choice:Input a number:                                                                                                         
2                                                                                                                                             
GoodBye!
```

Comment: Still need to check return value from `scanf))` and handle errors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your comment! You are absolutely right! I am working on it...

Comment: Sorry to be the curmudgeon but your input does not seem to handle EOF.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I really appreciate your comments! They help me as well as OP to handle the problem in the proper way. You can be as hard on me as you can, I am here to learn from the Masters. Thank you again for taking your time and correcting me. (I have updated the program.)

Comment: Even now, when I run your program, if I type control-D (I'm on Unix; that indicates EOF — on Windows, use control-Z), I get a screen full of lines saying `No letters! Input a number:`.  You have to test the `scanf()` result carefully.  When there's one conversion specification as here (one `%d`), it can return -1 (EOF), 0 (didn't find a number) or 1 (found a number).  On EOF, you need to stop trying to get more input.  (On the nit-picking end of things: if the program doesn't use the command line options, use `int main(void)`.  My default compilation options complain about unused variables.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your patience. I am on Windows running  `https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler`. It takes  `control-D` . Program would recognize it and quit via `2` case now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &userinput);` expects an `int` as the input. When you give a non-integer, `scanf()` won't assign it to `userinput`.

Check the return value of [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to see if it was successful. It returns the number of successful assignments it did.

When you give a string as input, `scanf()` won't accept it and will leave it in the input buffer unconsumed.

When you do `scanf()` again, the invalid input is still present in the input buffer and that is what the second `scanf()` tries to read. The same thing happens and this goes on. This is the reason behind your infinite loop.

To overcome this, you should consume the invalid input from the input buffer after displaying the message in `case 3`. Do something like

```
int ch;
while( (ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF );
```

This will consume from the input buffer till a `\n` is encountered. [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) return `EOF` on failure.

Edit: Standard C doesn't allow nested function definitions. The reason why you didn't get an error for that is probably because your compiler allows this as an extension. But it may not work for other compilers.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348095/why-are-nested-functions-not-supported-by-the-c-standard) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090975/function-definition-inside-another-function-definition-is-it-valid).

You could place the definition of `options()` within the `while` loop calling it or get the value for `userinput` as a return value or via a pointer to the variable passed to the function.