# Recursion function in C

Tags: c, function, recursion

I got this code as an exercise in my school:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int unknown(int a, int b)
    {
        if (b == 1) 
            return a;
        else 
            return a + unknown(a, b - 1);
    }
    printf("Value = %i", unknown(3, 4));
}
```

The outcome is "Value=12". I can't seem to understand why. 
AFAIK it should be a=3, b=4 and then 3+4, right?

Comment: Write down two columns for `a` and `b`, and work through their start values until you get to the correct answer.

Comment: What does this have to do with the comma operator? And tell your school that nested functions are not allowed in C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, kinda relevant... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/226150

Comment: Isn't this kind of off-topic?  This seems to be more about elementary mathematics than anything else.

Comment: It seems to me more of a lack of understanding of recursion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about elementary mathematics and not about programming.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I was surprised to see a nested function, and even more surprised to see it compiled when I tried it. It's a Gnu extension, apparently. http://stackoverflow.com/a/666593/10077

Comment: @devnull & the others; I really wouldn't consider this as *off-topic*... He needed help on understanding recursive functions in programming, which I think [slim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21882754/2736228) provided really well. An issue being too easy for me and you, shouldn't make it off-topic, if that was the reason.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Read the comment by AlexReynolds.  I would still say that this could be trivially solved by sitting with a pen and paper.

Comment: @devnull Yes, but hey, I could say that almost every programming question could be trivially solved with a pen and paper, and that shouldn't make those *almost every programming questions* off-topic. I hadn't said anything contradictory to being trivially solvable with a pen and paper anyway...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin excuse me, I didn't realise WHAT the command does, I thought it was a simple (a+a)*(b-1) or something. 
I thought this was a place to ask questions about programming not a "you don't even know math" insult clique. Sorry I bothered you.

Comment: @user3328369 Well, I should be the last person for you to refer about that. I have been saying the same all along, this type of a question should really be entirely appropriate to ask here. However, apparently some people were ***born*** with all the computational knowledge and have learned recursion during elementary school...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I must have understood wrong then, sorry about that (lack of coffee). :)

Answer (score 8):

The key to this is that unless `b`==1, `unknown()` calls `unknown()` - this is called *recursion*.

For brevity, I'm going to call the function *f* instead of *unknown*:

Some languages present functions like this in a clearer way with *pattern matching*; the equivalent in an imaginary pattern matching language might be:

```
f(x,1) := x
f(x,y) := x + f(x,y-1)
```

And so...

```
f(3,4) = 3 + f(3, 4-1)
       = 3 + f(3, 3)
       = 3 + ( 3 + f(3, 3-1))
       = 3 + ( 3 + f(3, 2))
       = 3 + ( 3 + ( 3 + f(3, 2 - 1)))
       = 3 + ( 3 + ( 3 + f(3, 1)))
       = 3 + ( 3 + ( 3 + (3)))
       = 12
```

I guess your homework is to decide what a better name for the function is than "unknown". Once you've decided, note that recursion is *not* the best way to implement that function unless your language has specific support for a feature called *tail recursion optimisation* (this might be a topic you want to shelve for later).

---

Also, others have noted that nested functions are not allowed in C -- even though your particular compiler might handle them. That means that although your program does this:

```
 int function1() {
     int function2(int x) {
         ...
     }
     int x = function2(3);
 }
```

... a standard C compiler would not allow it. The normal way is:

```
 int function1() {
     int x = function2(3);
 }

 int function2(int x) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: WOW it was way more complicated than I thought. Thank for you very much for your time, you just saved my a$$. :)
ps.: im using dev-c++ and we're instructed to make our code as clear as possible using nesting, but just for reading purposes

Answer (score 3):

Each time `a` is added to `a` for `b times`

```
a = 3
b = 4
```

So, four times `a` gets added which means `4 * 3 = 12`

**Edit:** a added to a, b times. -Dabo

Comment: a added to a, b times.

Answer (score 2):

Its the multiplication using recursive addition . Output should be `12`.  Finally function will return to `main`

```
3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 12
```

**Note:** Although you used nested function here and its working, but it is not allowed by C standard. Its a compiler extension.